# bootstrap 4 cards scrubles under mobile screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm making intro site with bootstrap 4 cards

check it at http://triangleslabs.com/mazenintro/

the problem that under small screen size the site changes into strange look

anyone can help?

Comment: what's wrong with it? Looks like it's responsive like intended.

Comment: Describe the problem specifically with relevant code or an example instead of the external link.

Answer (score 0):

`#cover` -> `height: 100%` forces the card-deck to center vertical align.

On a small screen you'll get the 3 cards to align with the top and bottom overflowing...

Remove that and it comes right.

(Remember that in responsive design you often loose the ability to change vertical control, as responsive design is a principle that takes screen width into consideration.)